# How to open .graphical DatePicker with a Custom Button in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, swiftui

**Context**

I would like to use `DatePicker` with the `.graphical` `DatePickerStyle`. However, I do not like to use the predefined `UI` coming with it to open the `DatePicker` itself.

My goal is to have a `Custom Button` *(see Image)* that opens the `DatePicker`, however, I did not find a solution for this.

[image: Image of the Custom Button]

---

**Code**

```swift
DatePicker(selection: $date, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
    CustomButton() // Even though you can add a View here, the DatePicker still contains the predefined UI.
}
```

---

**Question**

- How can I achieve my goal of having a `.graphical` `DatePicker` with a `Custom Button` to open it?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want to do ?

```
import SwiftUI

struct DatePickerButton: View {
    @State private var selectedDate = Date()
    @State private var showDatePicker = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    showDatePicker.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .padding(.trailing)
                }
            }
            
            if showDatePicker {
                DatePicker(
                    "",
                    selection: $selectedDate,
                    displayedComponents: .date
                )
                .labelsHidden()
                .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
                .frame(maxHeight: 400)
            }
            
         Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]